# Android: How can you align a button at the bottom and listview above?

Tags: android, listview, layout, alignment

I want to have a button at the bottom of the listview.

If I use relativeLayout/FrameLayout, it aligns but listView goes down to very botton.

(Behind the button at the bottom)

[image]

FrameLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnButton"
            android:text="Hello"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom" />
    </FrameLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

RelativeLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnButton"
            android:text="Hello"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Above two codes only work like the first image. What I want is second image.

Can anybody help?

Thank you.

Answer (score 188, accepted):

A `FrameLayout`s purpose is to overlay things on top of each other.  This is not what you want.

In your `RelativeLayout` example you set the `ListView`s height and width to `MATCH_PARENT` this is going to make it take up the same amount of space as its parent, and thus take up all of the space on the page (and covers the button).

Try something like:

```
<LinearLayout 
   android:layout_width="match_parent" 
   android:layout_height="match_parent" 
   android:orientation="vertical">
  <ListView 
     android:layout_width="match_parent" 
     android:layout_height="0dip" 
     android:layout_weight="1"/>
  <Button 
     android:layout_width="match_parent" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:layout_weight="0"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The `layout_weight` dictates how the extra space is to be used.  The `Button` does not want to stretch beyond the space it requires, so it has a weight of 0.  The `ListView` wants to take up all of the extra space, so it has a weight of 1.

You could accomplish something similar using a `RelativeLayout`, but if it is just these two items then I think a `LinearLayout` is simpler.

Comment: Solved my issue, but `android:weight` should be: `android:layout_weight`

Comment: @Mayra Your solution works great. However, is there a reason it only works with `android:orientation="vertical"`and not with the horizontal or no oriantation specified?

Comment: Eric, this should work with orientation=horizontal if you also reverse the values for layout_width and layout_height.   I believe that horizontal is the default orientation, so setting it is the same as not specifying.

Comment: But this solution does not handle the case where the listview is not long enough to fill the entire vertical space of the screen. If the listview just fills half of the screen, then the button appears right below the listview and hence ends up somewhere in the middle of the screen. In this case, how can we make the button appear always at the bottom?

Comment: android:layout_weight="0dip" is not true it should be android:layout_weight="0" any ways its a good approach

Comment: This answer is a better explanation than anything I've come across in the official documentation, which all just seems to explain stuff to people who already know it.

Comment: Best answer ever :) :)

Comment: How can I solve it if there are three elements, a header a footer and a listview?

Comment: @Merian - did you try setting the header and footer with `android:layout_weight="0"` , and the list itself as `android:layout_weight="1"`  ?

Answer (score 4):

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:background="#ffffff"
  >

    <ListView android:id="@+id/ListView01" 
      android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_weight="1">
    </ListView>

    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/FrameLayout01" 
      android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">
         <Button android:id="@+id/Button01" 
              android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
              android:text="button" 
              android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
        </Button>
    </FrameLayout>

  </LinearLayout>
```

Here is the design you are looking for.
   Try it.

Answer (score 4):

I needed two buttons side-by-side at the bottom.  I used a horizontal linear layout, but assigning `android:layout_height="0dp"` and `android:layout_weight="0"` for the buttons' linear layout didn't work.  Assigning `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` for just the buttons' linear layout did.  Here's my working layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp" 
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/new_button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="New" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/suggest_button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Suggest" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

I am using Xamarin Android, and my requirement is exactly the same as William T. Mallard, above, i.e. a ListView with 2 side-by-side buttons under it.
The solution is this answer didn't work in Xamarin Studio however - when I set the height of the ListView to "0dp", the ListView simply disappeared.

My working Xamarin Android code is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/ListView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_above="@+id/ButtonsLinearLayout" />
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@id/ButtonsLinearLayout"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I aligned ButtonsLinearLayout to the bottom of the screen, and set the ListView to be above ButtonsLinearLayout.

Answer (score 2):

`RelativeLayout` will ignore its children `android:layout_width` or `android:layout_height` attributes, if the children have attributes that properly define their `left` and `right` or `top` and `bottom` values, respectively.

To achieve the result on the right image, showing the list above the button, your layout should look like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@android:id/button1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@android:id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="@android:string/ok"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The key is to define `android:layout_alignParentTop` (defines `top` value) and `android:layout_above` (defines `bottom` value) in your `RecyclerView`. This way, `RelativeLayout` will ignore `android:layout_height="match_parent"`, and the `RecyclerView` will be placed above the `Button`.

Also, make sure you look into `android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing`, if you have a more complex layout and you still need to define these values.

Answer (score 0):

In your relative layout height of listview is `match_parent` which is fill_parent(for 2.1 and older) so best solution is if you want to use relative layout then first Declare your button then your list view, make list view position as above your button id, If you want button always at bottom then make it alignParentBottom..
Snippet is

```
<RelativeLayout 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/rl1"><Button 
 android:layout_width="MATCH_PARENT" 
 android:layout_height="WRAP_CONTENT" 
 /><ListView 
 android:layout_width="MATCH_PARENT" 
 android:layout_height="0" 
 android:layout_above="@id/listview"/></RelativeLayout>
```

This prevents your list view taking whole place and make your button appear..

Comment: (Warning: minor Android terminology pedantry ahead.) The deprecated term is "fill_parent", not "match_parent".  This makes sense to me because "fill" implies both dimensions while "match" suggests "the same as".

Answer (score 0):

@jclova one more thing you can do is use `layout-below=@+id/listviewid` in relative layout

Answer (score 0):

This will be the best and the most simple solution to the problem. Just add  `android:layout_above="@id/nameOfId"` in the layout that you want to move above with respect to that layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.sumeru.commons.activity.CommonDocumentUploadActivity">

    <ListView

        android:id="@+id/documentList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/verifyOtp" />


    <com.sumeru.commons.helper.CustomButton
        android:id="@+id/verifyOtp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="@string/otp_verification" />
</RelativeLayout>
```