# How to position an Android ListView above a view - without taking up the full space

Tags: android, android-layout

To allow users to submit comments, I have 2 views, vertically stacked. A ListView for displaying entered comments and a LinearLayout footer, for allowing the user to add a comment (which is basically an EditText and a button).

The footer must be anchored to the foot of the screen and the ListView must sit above it. Its similar to what you see on facebook for Android when you are adding comments.

However *I don't want the ListView to initially take up the full space* - I want it to take up only the space required to display its rows, but to be able to *grow into* the remaining space as the user adds comments - while always staying above the footer layout.

I've tried a LinearLayout as suggested here [Android: How can you align a button at the bottom and listview above?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4936553/android-how-can-you-align-a-button-at-the-bottom-and-listview-above)

However, this results in the ListView taking up all the space above the footer - when there is only a couple of comments - so its mainly empty and looks weird.

I have tried a RelativeLayout parent, where the footer is anchored using `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`..... Positioning the ListView above the footer using `android:layout_above="@id/footerLayout"` forces the same behaviour as above (ListView takes up all remaining space)... removing this allows the ListView to 'grow' but it overlaps the footer if its grows too big.

Cheers.

Comment: Do you want the footer to be anchored to the bottom? Or should it float below the listview?

Comment: It should be anchored at the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess this workaround will work!

```
<LinearLayout
    layout_width="MATCH_PARENT"
    layout_height="MATCH_PARENT"
    orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        layout_width="MATCH_PARENT"
        layout_height="0"
        android:weight="1"
        orientation="vertical">
        <YOURLIST
            layout_width="MATCH_PARENT"
            layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
    <YOURVIEW
         android:layout_width="MATCH_PARENT" 
         android:layout_height="WRAP_CONTENT" 
         android:weight="0"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It does indeed! I can't see how wrapping the LV in a the parent layout solves this... can you explain?

Comment: @Neil: it's the `android:weight` attribute used by the outer `LinearLayout` that makes the inner `LinearLayout` take up all the "unused" space. You could probably use it directly on the list, but I'm not sure of that.

Comment: The key is the android:weight="0" on the other view

Answer (score 2):

I guess one way to do it would be using the `android:fillViewport` attribute in the XML. See this blog post by Romain Guy: http://www.curious-creature.org/2010/08/15/scrollviews-handy-trick/

Comment: But I believe this would involve re-writing the ListView as a ScrollView?

Comment: @Neil, `ListView` extends `ScrollView`. No need to rewrite :)

Comment: No it doesn't. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html.

Comment: Oh, snap. You're right. Don't know why I was convinced of this. Thanks for pointing out.